# How to change the colors of icons in ModernCV

Tags: moderncv

I'm trying to use the icons in the same color they are shown on the net. For example I want to have my linkedin icon with color blue instead of dimmed gray. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions of the icons are found in `moderncviconsawesome.sty` (using default settings). You can modify these definitions to add colors to the icons.

Original definitions:

```
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {{\Large\faMobile}~}
\renewcommand*{\fixedphonesymbol}    {\faPhone~}
\renewcommand*{\faxphonesymbol}      {{\small\faFax}~}        % alternative: \faPrint
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}         {{\small\faEnvelopeO}~}  % alternative: \faInbox
\renewcommand*{\homepagesymbol}      {{\small\faGlobe}~}      % alternative: \faHome
\renewcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{{\small\faLinkedin}~}   % alternative: \faLinkedinSquare
\renewcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol} {{\small\faTwitter}~}    % alternative: \faTwitterSquare
\renewcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}  {{\small\faGithub}~}     % alternative: \faGithubSquare, \faGithubSquare
```

MWE that changes the LinkedIn color to blue:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[xing]{john\_doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\social[gitlab]{jdoe}
\social[skype]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\renewcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{{\color[HTML]{074786}\small\faLinkedin}~}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: another question, do you know how can I extend the social commands, to have only icons without texts that are embedded with links? Like only having twitter icon without any string infront of it.

Comment: @FarhoodET if you have a new question it is best to ask a new question using the Ask Question button on top of the page. The formatting of the text part of the social media entries is a bit complicated in moderncv and the question is also fairly different from changing the colors, so a new question is better I think. Also it might be confusing for readers: how do they know that the icon is a link?